# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp.urls'

Tags: python, django, modulenotfounderror

**I tried to change setting to below but doesn't work:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'myapp']
```

**my directory:**

```
manage.py
django_project
   __init__.py
   asgi.py
   settings.py
   urls.py
   wsgi.py
myapp
   migration
   __init__.py
   admin.py
   apps.py
   models.py
   tests.py
   urls.py
   views.py
```

it keeps showing ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp.urls'

**views.py from myapp:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, Httpresponse

def index(request):
    HttpResponse('Welcome!')
```

**urls.py from myapp:**

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index ),
    path('create/', views.index)
    path('read/1/', views.index)
]
```

**urls.py from django_project:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls'))
]
```

Thank you!

Comment: use full name of 'myapp.apps.MyappConfig', instead of only app name and check.

Comment: @AshishNautiyal I tried it but still doesn't work :(

Comment: which version of django and python you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

in `myapp/apps.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'myapp'
```

Maybe you need to set this ?
[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.name)

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but still doesn't work ㅠㅠ

Comment: I updated my answer with another suggestion, this is done in myapp/apps.py